# finding most recent file version from list of file path names with jumbled file names

Tags: eclipse, bash, grep

I recently lost a bunch of files from eclipse in an accidental copy/replace dilema. I was able to recover most of them but I found in the eclipse metadata folder a history of files, some of which are the ones I need. The path for the history is:

```
($WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history).
```

Inside there are a bunch of folders like 3e,2f,1a,ff, etc.. each with a couple files named like "2054f7f9a0d30012175be7013ca49f5b". I was able to do a recursive grep with a keyword i know would be in the file and return a list of file names (grep -R -l 'KEYWORD') and now I can't figure out how to sort them by most recently modified.

any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: As first, make a backup from the current state. if you going wrong can start again. `tar -cvpzf /some/path/backup.tgz /path/to/your/workspace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
find $WORK.../.history -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\n' | sort -nr | cut -f2- | xargs grep 'your_pattern'
```

Decomposed:

- the `find` finds all plain files and prints their modification time and path
- the sort `sort` sort them numerically - and reverse, so highest number comes first (the latest modified)
- the `cut` removes the time from each line
- the `xargs` run its argument for each file what get to it input,
- in this case will run the `grep` command, so
- the 1st file what the grep find - was the lastest modified

The above not works when the filenames containing spaces, but hopefully this is not your case... The `-printf` works only with `GNU find`.

For the repetative work, you can split the command to two parts:

```
find $WORK.../.history -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\n' | sort -nr | cut -f2- > /somewhere/FILENAMES_SORTED_BY_MODIF_TIME
```

so in 1st step you save to somewhere the list of filenames sorted by their modification times, and after you can repeatedly use the grep command on their content with:

```
< /somewhere/FILENAMES_SORTED_BY_MODIF_TIME xargs grep 'your_pattern'
```

the above command is usually written as

```
xargs grep 'your_pattern' < /somewhere/FILENAMES_SORTED_BY_MODIF_TIME
```

but for the `bash` is OK write the redirection to the start and in this case is simpler changing the `pattern` for the `grep` if the pattern is in the last place...

If you want check the list of filenames with modification times, you can break the above commands as:

```
find $WORK.../.history -type f -printf "%T@\t%Tc\t%p\n" | sort -nr >/somewehre/FILENAMES_WITH_DATE
```

check the list (they now contains readable date too) and use the next

```
< /somewehre/FILENAMES_WITH_DATE cut -f3- | xargs grep 'your_pattern'
```

note, now need to use `-f3-` and not `-f2-` as in the 1st example.